# How is the way to insert dynamically one pair to may unordered_list?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have one `unordered_map` and I want insert in a for dynamically the value iterated, but always the `std::unordered_map::insert` insert only once.

```
unordered_map<string, string> legalities;
vector<string> values = {"foo", "bar"};

for(auto& value : values) {
  legalities.insert({ "foo", value });
  cout << value << endl;
}

legalities.size(); // return 1
```

How I can insert in this way?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code, but I guess your expectations are wrong. What do you expect this code to do and what do you think is wrong about it?

Comment: @user463035818 the answer give me what i want: duplicated keys.

Comment: yes, you got the answer, but still the question is rather unclear because what you have is already the way to insert items into a unordered_map

Comment: @user463035818 obvious not! in unordered_map I CAN'T duplicate the keys.

Answer (score 5):

That's because `std::unordered_map` doesn't allow duplicate keys (`"foo"` twice).If you want duplicate keys you should use `std::unordered_multimap`.

Answer (score 3):

> **26.2.7 Unordered associative containers**
>    An unordered associative container supports unique keys if it may contain at most one element for each key. Otherwise, it supports equivalent keys. `unordered_set` and `unordered_map` support unique keys. `unordered_multiset` and `unordered_multimap` support equivalent keys.

So, you need to use `unordered_multimap` in case you want two objects with the same keys "foo" in the map.